# How do I create an array of resources using Jena?

Tags: resources, jena

I am using Jena and Java, and am reading a CSV file. For each line of the file there is a subject resource. Two subject resources, on adjacent lines, might have share the same value of a field in the line (e.g: both lines have the same process id). In this case, I need to combine the two  subject resources as each one represents a sub-process in production (for example).

My question is: how can I reference those two resources dynamically so that I can combine them? I came to the idea that when I find that they share the same property to store them in an array resource subjects. Is it the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

This question would be a lot easier to answer if you could show some sample data. As it is, I think you're focusing on the wrong bit of the question. If you can decide clearly what it *means* to have two rows in your CSV with identical process, and then you decide how you're going to encode that meaning in your RDF model, then the question of how to write the code - as an array  or whatever - will be much clearer.

For example (and I'm going to make up some data here - as I said, it would be easier if you show an actual example), suppose your CSV contains:

```
processId,startTime,endTime
123,15:22:00,15:23:00
123,16:22:00,16:25:00
```

So process `123` has, apparently two start and end time pairs. If you model this naively in RDF, you'll end up with a confusing model:

```
process:process123
    a :Process;
    process:start "15:22:00"^^xsd:time;
    process:end "15:23:00"^^xsd:time;
    process:start "16:22:00"^^xsd:time;
    process:end "16:25:00"^^xsd:time;
.
```

which would suggest that one process had two start times (and two end times) which looks nonsensical. However, it might be that in reality you have a single process with multiple episodes, suggesting one way to model it, or a periodic process which occurs at different times, or, as you suggested, sub-processes of a parent process. Or something else entirely (I'm only guessing, I don't know your domain). Once you are clear what the data means, you can produce a suitable RDF model. For example, an episodic process might be:

```
process:process123
    a :Process;
    process:episode [
        a process:Episode;
        process:start "15:22:00"^^xsd:time;
        process:end "15:23:00"^^xsd:time;
    ];
    process:episode [
        a process:Episode;
        process:start "16:22:00"^^xsd:time;
        process:end "16:25:00"^^xsd:time;
    ]
.
```

Once the modelling is clear in your mind, I think you can see that the question of how to produce the desire RDF triples from Java code - and whether or not you need an array - is much clearer. Equally importantly, you can think in terms of the JUnit tests you would write to test whether your code is behaving correctly.